# Quicker way to sum sections of an SQL column

Tags: php, sql

Say I have a table with 1million rows.  One column lists the "Group", and another lists "Sales".  The Group #'s range from 1 to 100,000 such that each Group has about 10 Sales entries.  I want to somehow summarize the data into 100,000 rows with the sum of Sales for each group rather than each individual sale.

My method so far has been to run a PHP loop from 1 to 100,000 where each iteration sends an SQL query to sum(Sales) WHERE Group=$i.  Then I can either echo it into an html table, or insert it into a new SQL table.  Problem is it takes hours this method.

Any tips on how I can improve this process?  Is there a way to write this as a single SQL query that will massively increase speed?  Thanks

Comment: Can you please add some data example?

Answer (score 4):

Just try a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT `group`, sum(sales)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY `group`
```

Edit to include back ticks for `group`. Without them you will receive an error

Comment: `Group` is a reserved word, escape it.

Comment: Update made. Thanks @u_mulder

Comment: Perfect!  I knew it was something simple.  This site is the best.

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid a SQL query in a loop unless there's no other solution. In this case, you can grab all the fields at once and have them in an array and add them up in PHP that way.

Comment: This is not an answer, it is just a comment.

Comment: And, in the context of prepared statements, it's not quite true.

Comment: I had planned on answering however the individual before me had already posted the answer - however I felt it was still important to get that point across - it should probably be moved to the comments. And it's not always the case, such as prepared statements, that's why it says "unless there's no other solution" i.e. - if it's not feasible to not do it inside of a loop.